# can I get acknowledgment for deleted mail from the recipient, using javamail api

Tags: smtp, jakarta-mail

I need to get acknowledgement for deleted mail from the recipient using java mail api is it possible to get this acknowledgement.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get an acknowledgment from the recipient when the recipient deletes a message?  No, there's no way to do that, using JavaMail or anything else unless you  have complete control over the mail reader that the recipient is using.

Comment: Thanks Bill, Got a usefull info, I will try next way to get a control of mail reader.